# How to tell IntelliJ IDEA that a method is checking for null value (ConstantConditions warning)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, suppress-warnings

We have a common method that we shared across our codebase to check if a response is empty, including `null` body. This is the signature of the method

```java
public static <T> boolean checkResponseEmpty(ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity);
```

Is there a way (maybe by adding annotation) to tell the IDEA that we've checked for `null` value on some fields, and it does not have to tell us a warning for `ConstantConditions` for that object and the fields (see screenshot).

[image: IntelliJ IDEA warning]

---

PS: I already know that I can suppress the warning with `//noinspection ConstantConditions` but I don't event want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA can see the check for 'response', but there are no explicit checks for 'getBody' or 'getArrivals'. First, you can extract 'response.getBody()' to a variable and check if it's not null. Second, you can use JetBrains '@NotNull' annotation on a return of 'getBody' and 'getArrivals' if it's suites your code logic (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html)